# Running AppEngine modules on predefined port numbers

Tags: google-app-engine, gradle

I am trying out the AppEngine modules feature and came to the point where I have a few modules, and each one of them needs to communicate with other modules as well as other external services. Is it somehow possible to specify to which port a module is going to bind? At the moment every time I run the application (btw, I'm using Gradle) modules get bound to different ports?

I tried using 

`appengine {
    httpPort = 8081
}`

in each module but this didn't help. The modules are still bound randomly?

Comment: Any news about that? I have the same problem but with appengine-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the JVM option as below.

**-Dcom.google.appengine.devappserver_module.{module_name}.port=8000**